# Devexpress Report Bands

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

Hi can i export not the whole report but instead the report bands of devexpress xtrareport? I want to have the header, body and footer pass onto different strings. It is possible? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have a InvoiceReceipt which has ReportHeader, Detail, ReportFooter what i want is to pass

```
ReportHeader => string header;
Detail => string items;
ReportFooter => string footer;
```

So when i get header it should have the header of the report in text format ( since it was exported as text ) and the rest follows.

OR

can i have the ReportHeader be exported as Text? same as ReportFooter and the Details part?

OR

can i have devexpress reports export to text a specific report by reportheader, reportfooter and details?

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to print out the data in the repeating part of the report, and not print the header and footer ? you know that you can delete/remove bands that you don't need

Comment: you almost got it. But i also want to pass the header, footer and the repeating part of the report to separate strings. is it possible? Also its not that i dont need parts of the report but i also need the whole report exported same as the report dissected and passed to separate strings.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with " want to pass the header, footer and the repeating part of the report to separate strings"

Comment: All my static report data i place it in the report header {one band per report} and the same goes for the footer, and the Detail band shows all my repeating parts

Comment: is it possible to show a screen shot of how you want it to look

Comment: I assume that you set the datacontext of the report, could you not build up those strings before you set the datacontext of the report, and build those string from your model/datacontext

Comment: hmmm. datacontext? actually i'm new at this and this report was created by someone.

Comment: Cools check the code that opens the report, cause the report gets its datacontext set, and all the info that goes into the report comes from the model that is set as the report datacontext

Answer (score 0):

Look for a code that almost looks like this

```
    XtraReport report = new XtraReport();

    ReportModel model = this.DataContext as ReportModel;

    report.DataSource = model;

    report.Report.DataSource = model.items;

    report.ShowPreviewDialog();
```

Cause building your header, detailband, and footer strings can be done by using the model that is set as the datacontext of the report, so there is no need to get the strings from the report header, detail band, footer

Answer (score 0):

```
on document viewer :-

public void Getnewreport()
        {
            XtraReport report = new XtraReport();
            // Create a report and bind it to a dataset. 
            report.DataSource = Datads;
            // Show the print preview. 
            report.ShowPreview();
        }

on designer
XtraReport objDevReport = new XtraReport();
                objDevReport.ShowPreview();
                objDevReport.ShowPreviewDialog();
```